# Does an app which encrypts messages with a cipher include cryptography? iOS App Store

Tags: ios, cryptography, appstore-approval, vigenere

I have created an app which uses a cipher, it has no backend and simply turns your message into an encrypted message on the screen to be copied to the clipboard. Whilst submitting for approval I have a question to answer which goes like this:

Is your app designed to use cryptography or does it contain or incorporate cryptography? (Select Yes even if your app is only utilizing the encryption available in iOS or macOS.)?

Does this question apply to my app, or more to higher levels of cryptography through communications and such?

Comment: Some people think that Base 64 is an encryption algorithm, so why not a classical cipher like Vigenère?

Comment: It seems like something more for security issues though?

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation of what its asking is-It applies to your app if you did include a (3rd party) cryptography library you didnt write, and "Is your app designed to use cryptography" I interpret as cryptography you implemented (without using a library or code you wrote). So I would say yes to the question asked. Only you know of course if you're using a library or not. My interpreatation is the question asks just seems to want to know are you using any cryptograhy in your app-and if you are are you using a 3rd party library or something else. Also a cipher can be considered as a type of cryptosystem e.g. a Vigenère cipher. A cipher changes the original message to an encrypted version (obviously there is another part of the cipher algorithm to decrypt thre message.) So I would say your app includes cryptography as it encrypts the message (as you mention).